# Laravel - get location in view and use it to sort posts in same view

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, coordinates, laravel-blade

When user enters my website, the route he visits is `'/'`, controller is `@getDashboard` and the view is `dashboard.blade.php`. In the `dashboard.blade.php` im using html5 geolocation to determine users lat & lng, after that im sending them to `@getDashboard` and from there i decide which posts should i show to which user example: 
If user is outside of Croatia, i do not want him to see Croatian posts. Obviously that cannot work since im already loading dashboard before im sending the lat & lng. 

I've come up with a few solutions, but i would like you to tell me which one is the best, or if it work at all.

Possible Solutions:

- Javascript sorting by lat & lng in the view

  - Pros: could work
  - Cons: that would mean that i will load all the posts in the world, and then decide which one to show/hide
- A route that loads before `'/'` and automatically submits lat & lng to `@getDashboard`

  - Pros: Will not load everything
  - Cons: Dosen't seem like a good solution, also if a person walks out of Croatia, the program wouldn't know it until my website is full refreshed.

If there is anything better, and im sure there is, please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: In your case I would have used IP to determine from which country the user is.

Comment: Hi, yes but the Country was just an example, i need really precise location, that is why i dont use dazzlepod json or something like that, sorry for not mentioning that.

Comment: Than I would recommend to load view blank and than load posts with XHR like Facebook has. I think it's the solution for you.

Comment: Can't you use ajax to load the posts after the page is rendered and the location is determined?

Comment: Hi @RobertoGeuke that would seem like a good solution, but would it be too complicated for someone who never worked with ajax?

Comment: It isn't that hard if you know some basic jquery. I think you can learn something from this tutorial. http://thingsaker.com/blog/ajax-laravel-controller-method. This code makes an ajax call, in the success function you should loop through the posts you retrieve in your response and show them with jquery. It's good to learn about how to use ajax, so I highly recommend to look into it!

Answer (score 0):

So your html5 geolocation should give you lat and longitudal co-ordinates... now each post is going to need a latitude and longitudal co-ordinate to compare it to.

The problem is that exact co-ordinates will not work so you will need to convert things into a radius using some math.

```
lat=asin(sin(lat1)*cos(d)+cos(lat1)*sin(d)*cos(tc))
IF (cos(lat)=0)
 lon=lon1      // endpoint a pole
ELSE
 lon=mod(lon1-asin(sin(tc)*sin(d)/cos(lat))+pi,2*pi)-pi
ENDIF
```

You will also need to set the maximum radius in which a "Post" can be seen and test if the users radius intersects with the posts radius.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering, i know how can i compare Post co-ordinates with Session co-ordinates, but i want to know how can i send session co-ordinates to a controller which controls the page i got session co-ordinates, so the problem is not how can i compare them, but how do i even get to display them? Thanks anyways, this seems useful.

Comment: Your best bet for incorporating this might be to use the google maps API.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation - This example will show you how to obtain the basic geolocational co-ordinates. You may want to create a map in the post editor that lets you click a location to set a marker and store the co-ordinates. When returning that value you will want to convert it to a radius or some other form of bounding box. The geometry library is your best bet.